# Concentration and support of a random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, terminology

Let $X$ be a random variable. Is there a difference between saying $X$ is *supported* on a set $A$, and saying $X$ is *concentrated* on a set $A$?

These are both common terminologies which, from context, appear to mean the same thing, but I can't find a written definition for the "concentrated" version.

Answer (score 0):

The support of a random variable (or a function) its a closed set. However a set where a measure is concentrated need not be closed, moreover, Im not sure about how much common is the expression "$X$ is concentrated in $A$" when $X$ is a random variable and not a measure, but its easy to think this as the set where the induced measure $P_X$ is concentrated.